# Multibit is not accepting the correct password any idea or possible bugs that i could fix

Tags: multibit, passphrase

just what i said. Multibit simply isn't accepting the password i used this morning to unlock it.

i have tried retyping it about a million times in a million different way.

does any one have any insight on this? it there a way to import the wallet into a different program and de-crypt it there?

Comment: Is your CAPS LOCKS on?

Answer (score 2):

That is certainly weird and it's most likely that you simply are typing a different password. To test this hypothesis, install MultiBit on another computer and import your wallet to see if it works. Perhaps your local MultiBit instance is corrupted.

Another option would be to try different versions of the client, although the wallet encryption algorithm hasn't changed. From the source code it seems to be using the [Bouncy Castle Crypto APIs for Java](https://www.bouncycastle.org/java.html): https://github.com/jim618/multibit/blob/master/src/main/java/org/multibit/crypto/KeyCrypterOpenSSL.java

Perhaps what you could also try is download that Bouncy Castle library and try decrypting your wallet directly using the raw library.